# Two datasource and repository/entity config

Tags: spring-boot

In a *Spring Boot 2.0* application, I am using *spring-data* with *hibernate* implementation.

I created two datasources.

Are there any special annotations to use on the entity or repo to specify what datasource to use?

Code of datasource

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vmax?stringtype=unspecified
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

Comment: Why dont you post the code you have written

Comment: Why do you need two datasources? If you need them then you need to define an id while defining the bean like `@Bean("anId")` and then in your Autowiring you should use `@Qualifier("anId")` to be able to resolve to specific datasource.

Comment: @Jobin posted config of datasource...

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla why two datasource? because i need to access two different schema of database...

Comment: Can you also post your config class, where you define the beans.

Comment: like i said, i use spring boot, it setup with this information the datasource, there is no bean.